# Function without return type

Tags: vb.net, function

In my project (which I inherited from someone) there are a lot of functions like:

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByVal s As String)
    ' Do something to public properties
End Function
```

And they are called like this:

```
DoSomething(s)
```

So the return value is ignored (which is object, as I see in the docs). Is it safe to change all these functions to Subs? Could I break something which isn't so obvious?

Comment: Another reason the functions could have no return type is if someone programmed with Option Strict off (for shame). You *should* be safe changing them each to `Sub` instead, but make sure that they're not actually returning something.

Comment: +1 Cody Gray. @_simon_, once you've eliminated all the compiler warnings, you could explore turning `Option Strict On`. Possibly do this piecemeal module-by-module, starting with the modules that you need to change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be safe. That's what Subs are for, this is really bad style by your predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you want to convert to Subs?  From your code the Function has **no return type** - in this situation I can't see there being any problem.

Comment: I would like to get rid of all compiler warnings (Function doesn't return a value on all code paths...)

Comment: Yea thats fine - like @Jules said this is was Subs are designed for

Comment: If no return type is specified, a return type of Object is assumed, so it is wrong to say there's no return type.